# How does copy, cut and paste work in a FireMonkey - HD Form designer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I am trying to write my first firemonkey - HD application

1. Create an firemonkey - HD application
2. On the form put a TLabel and change its Name.
3. Select the TLabel

In the Drop Down Menu select Edit 
  **Why are all the editing options disabled ?**

OR

In the Main Menu at the top of the screen select Edit
  **Why are all the editing options disabled ?**

Question: **What am I doing wrong ?**

Comment: Seems to be a bug indeed. Please report this as soon as QC has an XE2 entry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Appears to be a bug. Select another tab and back (or F12 into the text and back) and the Edit menu works properly. Click on anything other than the form and it stops working.

In a similar vein, sometimes hitting F12 to get from the text to form displays won't work either (again change tabs and back).

Comment: Yes, definitely a bug, and I can confirm it too.

Answer (score 0):

A bug, however if you check the Edit from the main menu instead of the right click, you will see that all of the options are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using XE6, and while cut works (lines can be pasted into Notepad), paste fails even with the F12 and click-tab tricks.